# Are all SwiftUI Views intermediaries for UIKit views?

Tags: swiftui

Are all SwiftUI Views intermediaries for UIKit views?  If so what are they wrappers for?

I think `NavigationView -> UINavigationController` etc...

Comment: Sometimes. Going through the source to https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect should give you a good idea about a lot of this.

Comment: Definitely no. And the tendency (observing from SwiftUI 1.0) that in the future there will be none at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely **NOT**.

First of all, there is no such thing as `UIKit` for other Apple platforms. So for example, you will see other counterparts like `AppKit` for macOS, which is enough to say **NO** to your question.

Second of all, Apple is hardly trying to build all SwiftUI components natively. But until all of them are available, they are using other platforms' existing components instead.

<sub>Maybe they will decide to not do it someday, who knows...</sub>

> [This repository](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) can help you see which is linked with which *for now*